# How to fix corrupted files when download from outlook using powershell

Tags: powershell, shell, outlook, automation

i have a powershell script that automatically download from outlook and save in the file i already set. the script works fine but then i realise that some of the attachment downloaded is corrupted. here is the script that i use.

```
Function saveattachmentexcel 
{
 $Null = Add-type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
 #olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
 #olFolderInbox = 6
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
 $folder = $nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
 $filepath = "D:\DMR Folder\"
 $folder.Items | Where {$_.UnRead -eq $True -and $($_.attachments).filename -match '.xlsm'} | ForEach-object {
      $filename = $($_.attachments | where filename -match '.xlsm').filename
    foreach($file in $filename)
    {
        $outpath = join-path $filepath $file
        $($_.attachments).saveasfile($outpath)
    }
     $_.UnRead = $False
   }
}
saveattachmentexcel
```

i do not know why this is happening. could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because you attempt to save every single attachment to the same file name on disk with the `$($_.attachments).saveasfile($outpath)` statement.

Change this:

```
$filename = $($_.attachments | where filename -match '.xlsm').filename
foreach($file in $filename)
{
    $outpath = join-path $filepath $file
    $($_.attachments).saveasfile($outpath)
}
```

to:

```
foreach($attachment in $_.attachments)
{
    if($attachment.Filename -like '*.xlsm'){
        $outpath = Join-Path $filepath $attachment.Filename
        # Only save this particular attachment to disk - not all of them
        $attachment.SaveAsFile($outpath)
    }
}
```